# Foreground service notification always shown for at least 5 seconds

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

I noticed some very strange behavior when testing foreground notifications on Android 9.

**Situation**: I have some *foreground* services where I don't know how long they'll need to run for, be it 1 second or a whole minute. Finally, when the service is done, it will call `stopForeground(true)`. This used to work fine on all Android 8, 9 and 10 devices, where `stopForeground(true)`, even if called immediately, always reliably removed the notification.

**Problem**: Testing on a **Fairphone 3** (and I hope someone else encountered this on some other devices, because for me this is not happening on any emulator or other device), `stopForeground` is not working as expected. Instead of immediately removing the notification, the notification always shows for *at least 5 seconds*, even if I call `stopForeground` straight away. These 5 seconds happen to be the exact 5 second limit of the dreaded error [Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground() - still a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57272203/2964379). Very peculiar! Reproducing this and checking whether your device is affected is very easy with the code below.

Inside `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<service
    android:name="<your package name>.TestService"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Class `TestService.java`:

```
package <your package name>;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public class TestService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        showNotification();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        showNotification();
        stopForeground(true);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void showNotification() {
        String channelId = "TEST";
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(channelId) == null)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel(channelId, "TEST NOTIFICATIONS", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT));
        startForeground(1, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId).setContentText("TEST NOTIFICATION").build());
    }
}
```

Finally, simply start the service (for example on button click) via `startForegroundService(new Intent(this, TestService.class));`

Has anyone else experienced this issue or is able to reproduce it with the code above? How can I fix or even just debug it, considering I'm testing on Android 9 and the behaviour is different simply because of the OEM?

Comment: try using IntentService or JobIntentService if possible

Comment: @AmitGoswami whether to use a `Service` or `IntentService` solely depends on one's use case and is not in the scope of this question, which aims to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I tried switching the above snippet to `IntentService` and `onHandleIntent` but the effect was all the same.

Comment: Hmm, so you're saying `stopForeground()` starts executing, and it blocks for ~5 seconds inside that function?

Comment: @greeble31 actually when debugging it seemed not to block the execution, but the notification is removed only after those 5 seconds.

Comment: So your issue could be restated simply as, "foreground notification always shows for at least 5 seconds on Fairphone 3". I can see why you would find this behavior curious or even objectionable, but at the same time I think the OEM is within their rights to do things this way. Discourages people from creating sneaky foreground services that "hide" in the background by only running for a few ms at a time. Have you considered using a regular old background service, instead, for those occasions when you know you won't have to execute for very long?

Comment: @greeble31 correct. Yes, I considered background services. For the use case I originally provided (stopping a service immediately after starting it) you're right, it's easy to use background services instead. But they're still not an option in my case. Take a look at my updated answer where it should be clear why not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Latest security patch claims that it's normal behaviour:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147792378

However I'm not sure why it's happening already on Android 9.

Comment: Balls! Thanks for finding that. I can imagine it's the case on Fairphone Android 9 specifically because they tend to be on the forefront when it comes to security patches, so they probably included the patch manually.

Comment: Super confusing behaviour that's not mentioned anywhere in the documentation (or is it?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you start your service, I saw someone using it and it worked.

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
```

Here is the link:
https://gist.github.com/codinginflow/1ab6d2689780be6d764215c3a40f2166