# Foreground notification still appearing after Intent service destroyed

Tags: android, intentservice, foregroundnotification

I have an IntentService and inside this instant service, in `onCreate`, I call the method `startforeground()`. I see then the notification when the intentService is created. However, when the IntentService is destroyed (going to onDestroy), I can see the notification for few seconds after that the service is destroyed. Why is that?

This is the code of the IntentService:

```
public class USFIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "USFIntentService";

    private static final int USF_NOTIFICATION_ID = 262276;
    private static final String USF_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "USF_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL";

    public USFIntentService() {
        super("USFIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG,"in onCreate");
        startUsfForegroundService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG,"in onDestroy");
    }

    private void startUsfForegroundService() {
        // Define notification channel
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel =
                new NotificationChannel(USF_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        // Build notification to be used for the foreground service.
        Notification notification =
                new Notification.Builder(this, USF_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_title))
                        .setContentText(getText(R.string.notification_message))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.usf_notification_icon)
                        .build();

        // Set the service as a foreground service.
        startForeground(USF_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onHandleIntent");
        if (intent != null) {
            doStuff();
        }
        Log.i(TAG,"End of onHandleIntent");
    }

}
```

I call this service like this:

```
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(intent);
startServiceIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(context, USFIntentService.class));
context.startForegroundService(startServiceIntent);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Foreground service notification always shown for at least 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526254/foreground-service-notification-always-shown-for-at-least-5-seconds)

Answer (score 3):

If **STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE** is supplied, the service's associated notification will be cancelled immediately.

If **STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH** is supplied, the service's association with the notification will be severed. If the notification had not yet been shown, due to foreground-service notification deferral policy, it is immediately posted when stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH) is called. In all cases, the notification remains shown even after this service is stopped fully and destroyed.

```
stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE) // remove with notification 

stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH) // remove only intent and not notification
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `Service#stopForeground` after your job is done to remove it

Comment: I actually tried to call stopForeground(true) in onDestroy, but I still see it few seconds after

Comment: @Bazouk55555 the answer was already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59856394/2964379), it's normal (even though weird) behaviour for the notification to show for 5 seconds after calling `stopForeground`. This also means that Anton's answer is irrelevant and is not attempting to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [stopForeground(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#stopForeground(boolean))  when you finish doing the stuff. So that your service gets immediately removed from foreground state and the parameter `true` ensures that the notification will be removed.

Comment: I actually tried to call stopForeground(true)  in onDestroy, but I still see it few seconds after

Comment: in onDestroy (of the IntentService)

Comment: try calling it in `onHandleIntent` itself. `onDestroy` may be called after a delay

Comment: It is the same (Actually I see onDestroy called but I still see the notification)

Comment: @Bazouk55555 @Bazouk55555 the answer was already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59856394/2964379), it's normal (even though weird) behaviour for the notification to show for 5 seconds after calling `stopForeground`. This also means that Antonio's answer is irrelevant and is not attempting to answer the question.